# trace of likelihood in pymc

Tags: python, trace, pymc, mcmc

Is there a way to access the trace of the likelihood in pymc? I declare the likelihood as:

```
@pymc.observed
def likelihood(value=1, data=data, model=model):
    chi2 = 0.0
    [...]
    return np.exp(-chi2/2.0)
```

But if I attempt the give the following arguments (as one would do for deterministic and stochastic variables):

```
@pymc.observed(plot=False, trace=True, name='likelihood')
```

It does not appear in the list of the traces.

Am I missing something? How to recover the values of "likelihood"?

Comment: Hi, a hack probably is to create a dummy deterministic variable which returns the same value as the `likelihood` function you defined.